# Can I publish Math Solutions over here and let the discussion grow?

Tags: discussion

Can I put solutions of Mathematical Problems over here, and let people discuss on it ? I undertsand this is not Meta-Math section, but I also do not have permission to riase question over there (needed 5 points).

Comment: upvote to give you the necessary points. Don't really like this system in the low points range.... (no comments... srsly? WHY?)

Comment: @example: Because you don't want to allow transient commentators. You want to get the people to know the community a little bit before they start writing comments everywhere.

Answer (score 20):

No, this is a Q & A website, not a discussion forum